# Seleção múltipla no Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Gostaria de expandir o cursor para a próxima palavra igual a que está selecionada, é semelhante ao `CTRL + F` porém faz uma cópia do cursor para onde a palavra selecionada foi encontrada, podendo assim alterar mais de um lugar do código ao mesmo tempo.

- Usando o `Sublime` ou o `Atom` a mesma função se encontra após selecionar a palavra, usando `CTRL + D`.

O `Visual Studio` possuí um atalho para função equivalente?

Não encontrei na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx#editors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe atalho nativo.

Mas achei um plug-in que pode ser baixado [aqui](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f301cf82-e80b-4b92-9e5c-ef7985ae6702?SRC=Home), e conta com os seguintes atalhos.

- `CTRL + D` - Adiciona um cursor para a próxima palavra selecionada
- `ALT + CLICK` - Adiciona um cursor na área do click
- `ALT + CLICK DUPLO` - Adiciona um cursor na área do click e seleciona a palavra
- `ESC` - Volta para o modo de cursor único

É um plug-in (atalho) que vale a pena investir um tempo para aprender pelo fato de diminuir o trabalho na hora da codificação/digitação.

---

1. Após está dúvida resolvi escrever [este breve artigo](https://pmargreff.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/atalhos-do-cursor-para-o-sublime-text-e-o-visual-studio/) sobre
   atalhos, que contém parte da resposta.